# JsonPath: find an element in an array by field

Tags: java, json, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath, jayway

I have an anonymous array of objects and I'd like to find an object by a specific field.

I tried this:

`jsonPath.get("$.[?(@.name == 'David')]")`

but I'm getting the following error:

```
Invalid JSON expression:
Script1.groovy: 1: Unexpected input: '                         $.[' @ line 1, column 29.
                            $.[?(@.name == 'David')]
                               ^

1 error
```

How do I fix that?

The json is:

```
[
 {"name": "David"}, {"name": "Ron"}, {"name": "Dana"}
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is a bit ambiguous, But the syntax is incorrect, `Json path` syntax uses `Groovy's GPath` notation

```
js.getString("find {it.name == 'David'}")
```

Comment: Not sure I get the syntax. What is `it`?

Comment: `it` operator in `Groovy` is similar to `@` operator in `Jayway`

Answer (score 0):

You may need

```
$.[?(@.name == 'David')]

=>  $.data[?(@.name == 'David')]
    $.response[?(@.name == 'David')]
    $.body[?(@.name == 'David')]
    ...
```

The name depends on when you extract your response

Comment: The array is anonymous (look at the JSON example please)

Comment: Only OP know that, but It's should not be anonymous lol

Answer (score 0):

Because You are using json Array ,
do use - $[0] ,
since david is on first index.

Comment: This is just an example. The placement is arbitrary

Comment: Agreed, que was ambiguous.